# Weird object rotation even with rotation constraints frozen (Unity Engine)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, game-physics

I have a game in a 3D world space. The gameplay is in 2D. So, the player has position frozen on 1 axis and rotation frozen on 2 axes. Position freeze works fine. However, some of the players experience unwanted object rotation during the gameplay even with frozen constraints (I have never encountered such an issue during BETA-test)

[image: Object wierd rotation.]

Constraints while I test it for myself:

[image]

My code (Player movement script)

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public int clickForce = 500;
    private Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);
    public float speed;
    public Slider staminaBar;

    private void Start()
    {
        Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.centerOfMass = Vector3.zero;
        rb.inertiaTensorRotation = Quaternion.identity;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Confined;

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            if (staminaBar.value > 0.25)
            {
                var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

                float enter;

                if (plane.Raycast(ray, out enter))
                {
                    var hitPoint = ray.GetPoint(enter);
                    var mouseDir = hitPoint - gameObject.transform.position;
                    mouseDir = mouseDir.normalized;
                    rb.AddForce(mouseDir * clickForce);
                }

                Plane playerPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
                Ray rayy = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                float hitdist = 0.0f;

                if (playerPlane.Raycast(rayy, out hitdist))
                {
                Vector3 targetPoint = rayy.GetPoint(hitdist);
                Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPoint - transform.position);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there any other rigidbodies inside the main one? Also is the object close to the origin of the scene? Things can get weird when you move far away.

Comment: The object consists of 6 children with mesh colliders (no rigidbodies). One player faced this issue in 20 points from the origin of the scene, another player in 210-220.

Comment: are you sure it is not a problem with the collision? Without them is it working?

Comment: The glitch is hard to spot, however, child objects have some mesh colliders inside each other (intersecting). Maybe, this thing causes an issue?

Comment: Looks like you're mixing physics forces with direct transformations. Rigidbody constraints will have no effect in this case.

Comment: @MaxKreslavsky Iggy is referring to this line in particular `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);` which overrides any rigidbody constraints.

Comment: Thank you for your support. The rotation system сode is rewritten and everything seems to work fine.

Comment: @MaxKreslavsky What did you do to fix it?

Comment: Well, actually it doesn't. I'll try your suggestion @Ruzihm

Comment: @MaxKreslavsky Interesting... just as a personal note I'm sure it annoys you when you have a problem, search the internet for people with a similar problem, find a post on stack overflow or a forum and the last contribution is a comment or post that says "nevermind got it"... I don't know if that was what was about to happen but please don't do that lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Iggy indicated, assigning to the transform ignores and overrides rigidbody constraints. To fix this, you can restrict the local up axis to be in its current direction using some vector math and the 2nd parameter of `Quaternion.LookRotation`. Explanation in comments:

```
if (playerPlane.Raycast(rayy, out hitdist))
{
    Vector3 targetPoint = rayy.GetPoint(hitdist);
    Vector3 targetDir = targetPoint - transform.position;
    // Find direction orthogonal to both targetDir and current local up.
    // this will become local right.
    Vector3 newLocalRight = Vector3.Cross(transform.up, targetDir);
    
    // If local up and target dir are colinear, do something sensible
    // like not changing the rotation
    if (newLocalRight == Vector3.zero) 
    { 
        /* something sensible */
        /* doing nothing may be the sensible choice */ 
    }
    else 
    {
        // If they are not colinear, determine the direction perpendicular to local up 
        // and local right. This will be the fixed forward direction.
        Vector3 newLocalForward = Vector3.Cross(newLocalRight, transform.up);

        // Assign a rotation using the fixed forward direction, and the current local up
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newLocalForward, 
                transform.up);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, 
                speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
 
}
```

Comment: That's a smart move. After 10 min of testing, no glitches appeared. I'll test it more, but thanks anyway!